# DependencyObject cannot find governing FrameworkElement for target element, even when that object is in the Logical Tree of a FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After researching a bit on the `Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element` error, I found out dependency objects cannot really have bindable dependency properties unless they are FrameworkElements or are in the element tree of one.

However, I have a FrameworkElement which owns DependencyObjects, and I cannot send bindings to those DependencyObjects properties even though they are part of the FrameworkElement logical tree.

I'm writing a complex custom control with sub elements, and I need those sub elements to be DependencyObjects (but not FrameworkElements, because they get polluted with lots of properties which don't get used, and it could confuse users), and I also need their DependencyProperties to be bindable.

What am I missing? Is there anything else I need to tell the DependencyObjects so they're aware they are in a Logical Tree? Should I just make them Freezables even if it makes no sense for them to be frozen?

Cheers

Comment: Any dependency property is bindable, just not any works without explicit Source. As for your question: as of now it seems that if your property is not part of visual or logical tree - your only option to make it inherit parent data context is indeed make it Freezable.

Comment: @Evk: After a bit of research and playing around, I've found out my properties won't show up on the Live Tree Inspector. I need to investigate this further, as I was sure overriding LogicalChildren enumerator would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you conclusions & inferences are not entirely correct.

***First thing*** is in `WPF` everything is derived from `DependencyObject`. `FrameworkElement` Class is not any different. If you look at the hierarchy of the  `FrameworkElement` classs It's like below Order:

> ***`DependencyObject` --> `Visual` --> `UIElement` -- > `FrameworkElement`***

So if you try to create a ***`Dependency Property`*** in a class that is derived from any of the above classes, it will work just fine(***excluding direct Binding but the Other way Binding Works(see example below)***). There must be a problem with your `CustomControl` (Not sure you are using a `CustomControl` or `UserControl`) code .

> ***But classes derived from `UIElement` can also have `DependencyProperties` that can be bound to other elements.***

see `UIElement` class, It has lot of `DependencyProperties`.

[image: UIElement]

Please share the code of your control, we can look into that.

***UPDATE:***

***Here is an example how a `DependecyObject's` `DependencyProperty` can be bound:***

***`DependencyObject` Implementation:***

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Button = new Button();
        Button.Width = 500;
        Button.Height = 400;
        Button.Content = "Bound to Window Height";
    }

    private Binding height;
    public Binding Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set 
        {
            height = value;
            ApplyBinding();
        }
    }

    public Button Button { get; set; }
    private void ApplyBinding()
    {
        this.Button.SetBinding(Button.HeightProperty, this.Height);
    }

}
```

***A `UserControl` Which uses Our `DependencyObject` Implementation:***

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyClass MyClass
    {
        get { return (MyClass)GetValue(MyClassProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyClassProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyClass.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyClassProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyClass", typeof(MyClass), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MyClassPropertyChanged)));


    private static void MyClassPropertyChanged(DependencyObject DO, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var MUC = DO as MyUserControl;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var myClass = e.NewValue as MyClass;                
            MUC.MyCanvas.Children.Add(myClass.Button);
        }
    }

}
```

***And Finally Binding:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflowTempProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"  Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackOverflowTempProject"     
    Height="{Binding ElementName=UIContent,Path=MyClass.HeightReplica,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    >
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="UIContent" >
    <local:MyUserControl.MyClass>
        <local:MyClass Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=ActualHeight,Mode=OneWay}" />
    </local:MyUserControl.MyClass>
</local:MyUserControl>
```

> So as output of above program when `Height` of our `Window` changes,
>   it will reflected back to our `MyClass` component's Button `element`
>   like we have done binding to `Button` itself in `XAML` code. ***So the
>   `Myclass` is a interface between it's logical parent control & it's
>   children elements for specifying the exposed properties/bindings***
>   and defining the behave of them corresponding to the child elements,
>   which actually will be visible on the UI and `MyClass` will work only
>   like a filter for idiomatic uses.

Comment: Author means a different thing. Try to do <local:MyClass HeightReplica="{Binding ActualHeight}" /> and you will see what is the problem (it won't work). Now inherit your MyClass from Freezable and it will work then.

Comment: @Evk Not sure about Freezable use here, but other than that, you are kind of repeating what i explained above. All my point was saying, if OP was doing something like binding the DP in dependencyObject he can do it in theopposite way from other UI elements, if feasible for him.

Comment: @Evk speaking of Freezable I remember it caused problems with binding and/or with Binding behavior(DP value reflection i remember, though not very sure), so kind of risky to use

Comment: WPF developers handle freezables in a special way exactly to allow use case like above, for example to allow binding SolidColorBrush.Color inside Button.Background. See here for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickkramer/2006/08/17/whats-an-inheritance-context/. In most cases you cannot reverse that binding. Though I don't like to inherit from freezable just to allow such behevior - it seems to be the only option for now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot ask the users of my component to write reverse-bindings for it instead of regular ones. I understand DependencyProperties work on DependencyObjects, but the DataContext isn't inherited unless we're talking about a Freezable or a FrameworkElement / FrameworkContentElement. And both of these classes come with a lot of baggage.

Comment: @AbelToy So your components are not visuals(displayed on UI)? may be that's a very important question here , what are your components and what they do? can you give a brief?

Comment: @KyloRen: I'm writting a XAML wrapper for an existing Chart component, which allows to write the charts in a more idiomatic way. What I'm doing is make each "Series" a Component, in the sense that you can place them as children of the chart, and they have dependency properties. However, their rendering is handled internally by the inner chart, so in that sense they are not part of the tree.

Comment: @AbelToy What are these chart components? DependencyObject or FremeworkElement or something else?

Comment: @AbelToy  As much as I can imagine your design I've updated the answer. So MyClass has a component(Button) that will get rendered at UI and MyUserControl will contain MyClass object, and will render the button. Myclass is the component that wraps the Button and users will be able to set bindings on this object. MyuserControl will internally get the Button object and render it at UI, however the binding will be set by MyClass. Does this covers your fix?

Comment: @KyloRen: Not really. I ended up using Freezables, that does work.

Comment: @AbelToy are you sure they are working correct? at first thought they may look like easy option but I think as they create immutability objects so be careful with them, sometimes binding can behave unexpectedly for them. Also they will hit performance a little. and thanks for replying.

Comment: @KyloRen: It's not ideal, but I couldn't get anything else to work.

Comment: @AbelToy if you are using pure WPF lib, upload a sample on web, I can look into that.

Comment: @KyloRen Same case in another charting library... currently I inherit from FrameworkElement, I am maybe changing to Freezable just to remove all the undesired properties https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts